# How to swap two elements of an array with empties in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, swap, splice

I have an array and I want to swap two elements in the array. If the array is non-empty, I can simply do:

```js
const swap = (arr, a, b) => {
    const temp = arr[a]
    arr[a] = arr[b]
    arr[b] = temp
}
```

and the function can correctly swap the value of the index `a` and `b` in the array `arr`.

However, if the array has some empty elements, such as `[1, , , ,]`, and the result of the `swap` will be `[undefined, empty, 1, empty]`, while the expected result should be `[empty × 2, 1, empty]`. So how do I modify the `swap` function so that the result will be correct. Or is there any way to make a specific index to be empty in an array?

Also failed:

```js
const swap = (arr, a, b) => {
    const temp = arr[a]
    arr.splice(a, 1, arr[b])
    arr.splice(b, 1, temp)
}
```

---

Original Problem:

I have an array `let arr = [1, , , ,]` (which will show `[1, empty × 3]` in console) with length 4, and I want to move the first element to the third, that is: `[empty × 2, 1, empty]`. How do I achieve that?

I have tried `splice` and directly assign value to the array but they won't work.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: "won't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need splice - combined with shift to get the first item

```js
let arr = [1, , , ,]

console.log(arr)

arr.splice(2, 0, arr.shift());
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have updated my question. Sorry for the inconvenience. My question is that I want to swap two elements in an array even if some elements are empty. Do you have any idea of how to approach that?

Comment: Your elements are NOT empty, they are undefined when created in a sparse array with commas

Comment: Oh, I see. So the "empty" in console will act exactly the same as "undefined". Thank you.